# Atom and TypeScript, compile several modules into one *.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, atom-editor

I have a project with 4 .ts files, and i have been trying to compile them into a single .js file. The problem i'm experiencing is that any save on any file generates a .js compilation of that file (without the reference paths included).

If i add the "out" key in my tsconfig.json, nothing is compiled, e.i no file is outputted. Any ideas of where i might be messing up?

This is my starting point, index.ts
[image]

My tsconfig.json
[image]

This is how i want it to be outputted, this is from my eclipse setup that currently works perfectly. I'd much rather use Atom though.
[image]

Edit: This is the tsconfig.json with "out" defined.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to include `out` to `tsconfig.json` in the `compilerOptions`? `out` parameter `Concatenate and emit output to single file` see documentation https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options

Comment: Yeah, when i add "out", nothing is compiled, (no file is generated). I edited my question with an image of the tsconfig.json and the "out" key.

Comment: I'm an idiot, "F6" to compile works. However the save on build broke when adding"out". Would be nice to not have to hit "F6" every tome i want to compile.

Comment: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md 

Not supported : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/206

Comment: Ok, so "out" is bad. How can i setup my project without "out", to achieve the workflow i want?

Comment: Browser? use `amd` and http://requirejs.org/ and associated `r.js`
----------------

Node? use `commonjs` no need to concatenate in node :)

Comment: Yeah i figured. The code looks so nice without the module and require cluttering, guess it will have to suffice when it's not server side. Thanks!

Comment: webpack or browserify also works and you can leave the requires to be node-style.